# How to force spaces between 2 elements when position:absolute with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a menu that shows up when the mouse is on a `div`, with some buttons at the top of the `div` and some at the bottom.

```css
.session {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
.button {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer
}
.top-menu, .bottom-menu {
    display: none;
}
.session:hover .top-menu{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    right: -20px;
}
.session:hover .bottom-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -20px;
}
.big-box {
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
}
.normal-box {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
}
.small-box {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-box session">
    <div class="top-menu">
        <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
        <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
        <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
        <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="normal-box session">
    <div class="top-menu">
        <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
        <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
        <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
        <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="small-box session">
    <div class="top-menu">
        <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
        <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
        <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
        <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[The JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9h2nroza/)

It works fine, but as you can see when you move your mouse to the bottom blue session, the buttons are covering each other. I want it to be using spaces below when the section is too small. Normally when I have `position: relative`, it will automatically push the other div into the next line, but I am not able to find a way to achieve the same effect without using `position: absolute`. In the actual case, the height of the section depends on the content it contains, so it is not possible to hard-code the position for a specific div.

So, is there a way, using only CSS, for me to either making it leaving some spaces when using `position: absolute` or is there a way I can be using `position: relative` to achieve the same effect?

P.S. There is already one answer. It is great, but it would be even better if it is possible to do the job without flex box.

Comment: Why not if the space is that small, and from your fiddle you're manually making each section of buttons just have them in a single div, and cut out the `bottom-menu` or are you dynamically building the html?

Comment: @user1273587 I've moved your JS Fiddle code into a Stack Snippet as the code needs to be included in the question itself (just in case the fiddle disappears).

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor layout method. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Aravona The height is depending on the content it contains and the content is dynamically generated.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know it is a poor layout method, but do you have ways to make the same effect without using absolute positioning? I accept answer that is not using absolute positioning too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: absolute;` takes `.top-menu` and `.bottom-menu` out of the document flow so they will not be aware of each others position on the page. This means they will overlap and not effect the position of other elements on the page.

`position: relative;` will not be suitable because this will move the element from where it is drawn on the page, meaning it would be difficult to position `.bottom-menu` at the bottom of the parent element without resorting to pixel values.

With some restructuring and use of the `flexbox` model, it is possible to get `.bottom-menu` to move if `.top-menu` encroaches on its space.

The following changes are required:

- Wrap `.top-menu` and `.bottom-menu` in a new `div` called `.menu`
- Add the following rules for `.menu`:

  - `display: none;` to hide it by default
  - `flex-direction: column;` to tell the child elements to arrange themselves from top to bottom
  - `justify-content: space-between;` to tell the child elements to be evenly distributed. One at the top, one at the bottom
  - `left: 100%;` to show the menu on the right of its parent
  - `min-height: 100%;` to tell the menu to be the entire `height` of its parent by default
  - `position: absolute;` to allow the `left` `position`ing to work
- Add the following rules for `.session:hover .menu`:

  - `display: flex;` to tell its children to use the `flexbox` model and to show the menu when its parent is hovered
- Remove `.session:hover .top-menu` and `.session:hover .bottom-menu`

```css
.session {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  left: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.session:hover .menu {
  display: flex;
}
.big-box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}
.normal-box {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
.small-box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-box session">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
      <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
      <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="normal-box session">

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
      <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
      <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="small-box session">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
      <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
      <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative method**

If IE8 support is required then `flexbox` isn't an option. Fortunately we can achieve similar results using the same markup but by using `position`ing and `padding`:

- Add the following rules for `.menu`:

  - `box-sizing: border-box;` to ensure that `padding` is included in the `height`
  - `padding-bottom: 22px;` is bottom `padding` equal to the `height` of `bottom-menu`. This will be used to "reserve" space for the `bottom-menu`
- Add the following rules for `.session:hover .menu`:

  - `display: block;` to show the menu when its parent is hovered
- Add the following rules for `.bottom-menu`:

  - `bottom: 0;` to `position` it at the bottom of its parent `.menu`. This will place it in the "reserved" `padding` space at the bottom
  - `position: absolute;` to allow the `bottom` `position`ing to work

The principle behind this is that because `.top-menu` is in the document flow it will cause the parent `.menu` to expand in `height` to fit it. By adding `padding` to the bottom of `.menu` the `.bottom-menu` can be `position`ed `absolutely` because it will always use that space and will not obscure `.top-menu`.

```css
.session {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  left: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  position: absolute;
}
.session:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
.bottom-menu {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.big-box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}
.normal-box {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
.small-box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-box session">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
      <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
      <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="normal-box session">

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
      <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
      <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="small-box session">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <div class="button-1 button">1</div>
      <div class="button-2 button">2</div>
      <div class="button-3 button">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <div class="button-a button">a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer..... but sadly I need to support IE8 too.... and even for Chrome, they have a different syntax of display: box and display: flex. Upvote but want to wait a bit before accepting the answer.

Comment: No problem, I've had a rethink given your new conditions and have come up with an alternative solution which doesn't require `flexbox`.

Comment: @user1273587 Is my second suggestion suitable given that it doesn't use `flexbox`?

Comment: Ops, I missed that. So I should choose the reason to be award this answer when setting up bounty. Now I need to wait 22 hours more before I can award the bounty.

Comment: @user1273587 No worries, sorry, I didn't realise I didn't tag your name in my original comment after I had made the change as it could have saved you the bounty. Thanks.